# Deferred Binding Generators for non-GWT Java code

Tags: java, compiler-construction, build, code-generation

A project I am working on requires some code generation based on a set of annotations.  I am interested in reducing the startup cost of processing the annotations and generating code which requires moving the analysis and code generation out of runtime/startup into the compile time phase of the application.  The functionality I am trying is very similar to what Deferred Bindings Generators handle for GWT.

[GWT Wiki:](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html)

> Deferred Binding is a technique used by the GWT compiler to create and select a specific implementation of a class based on a set of parameters.

...

> Generators are classes that are invoked by the GWT compiler to generate a Java implementation of a class during compilation.

Through Deferred Binding Generators, GWT can essentially avoid reflection because the reflection/analysis and subsequent code generation is handled at compile time.  This makes the startup of GWT based applications extremely fast.

Are there any frameworks that handle the concept of Deferred Binding Generators for regular java?

As a follow on question, a goal of this is also to integrate with IDE compilation.  Will this require some sort of IDE plugin for Eclipse, Intellij, and others?  Also, how well will this integrate with the various build tools out there (Maven, Ant, Gradle, etc)?